# Unable to find file 'normnfc.nlp' of multi-file assembly 'mscorlib.dll'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, outlook-addin, outlook-2007, mscorlib

I'm getting this error when building a setup project for an outlook 2007 addin from Visual Studio 2010.

There is nothing complicated to the setup project, just using the standard mechanism.

I know it is unable to find the file. 
What is normnfc.nlp? 
What does it do?
Where can I find it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is one of 5 external resource files for mscorlib.dll.  It contains Unicode character mapping data, used by string.Normalize().  It is stored in the GAC in the same directory as mcorlib.dll.  For .NET 4 that would be C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089.  GAC_64 for the 64-bit version.

Very unhealthy if this file is missing.  First thoroughly check the disk drive.  Reinstall .NET 4.  Ask questions about drive health at superuser.com